# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException в двумерном массиве

Tags: java, массивы, исключения, index

Код:

```
package com.company;
public class Array {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        double array[][] =new double[5][5];

        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<=5; j++){
            array[i][j]=Math.sin(i+j);
            System.out.println(array[i][j]);
        }   }
    }
}
```

порождает вывод:

`0.9092974268256817`
`0.1411200080598672`
`-0.7568024953079282`
`-0.9589242746631385`

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>    at com.company.Array.main(Array.java:8)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81689/discussion-on-question-by-kachunskyy-igor-arrayindexoutofboundsexception--).

Answer (score 2):

Массивы индексируются от 0 до (длина-1).

Такиим образом, обращение к элементу `array[1][5]` выходит за пределы массива и порождает исключение `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

У вас есть две опции

Изменить циклы:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
    array[i][j]=Math.sin(i+j+2); // +2, потому что теперь обе переменные меньше на 1
    System.out.println(array[i][j]);
  }   
}
```

Или починить индексы:

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
  for(int j=1; j<=5; j++){
    array[i-1][j-1]=Math.sin(i+j);
    System.out.println(array[i-1][j-1]);
  }   
}
```

Comment: Брате ти мені допоміг ДЯКУЮ я так затупив!!!!!

Comment: Завжди будь ласка =)

Comment: @vp_arth, не хочу быть лаской! Котэ ещё сойдёт.